# Unable to display custom fields on WooCommerce product pages

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I've set up some custom fields using the existing 'custom fields' panel on a WooCommerce product page. I'm unable to display these on the front end. My technical knowledge is limited but I've tried every example and code snippet found elsewhere on this site, including;

```
// Display Custom Field Value
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field', true );
```

and a bunch of others.

However, when I use `the_meta()`, which, from what I understand, should display all meta, it gives me this on the front end:

```
frs_woo_product_tabs: a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:12:"License Info";s:2:"id";s:16:"tab-license-info";s:7:"content";s:19:"License description";}}
```

It doesn't appear to recognize any of the custom fields that I've entered. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory

Answer (score 2):

Where are you pasting that code?

The code snippet needs to be put in the right spot.
So you need to copy the content-product.php template from the woocommerce plugin folder and place it in your theme folder in a "woocommerce" folder.
Then paste that code within the Loop.

---

Updated Answer:

Okay so I believe that you need to use the [get_post_custom](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) function.

Take note of the Name of your custom field. Then we can something like this to output the results:

```
<?php

  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields["Name of your Field"];
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
      echo "<strong>$key: </strong> $value <br />";
  }

?>
```

Comment: I used a csv file to populate the custom fields and they saved fine, but when I use echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_field', true ); it won't display anything. If I manually add and save the custom field on the product page it displays the fields. Also, if I use <?php the_meta(); ?> it displays all of the csv imported fields. I really need to use the CSV option because of the quantity involved as well as selecting which fields to display. Not really sure how to proceed

Comment: Where are you using echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_field', true ); ?!

Comment: Hi Nath, I'm placing it in the description.php found in woocommerce\single-product\tabs

Comment: Okay good. Try <?php $custom = get_post_custom($post_id); var_dump($custom); ?> And let us know if that spits anything out.

Comment: It sure did, but not what I was expecting! It's rather long and has been cut short by the character limit here; array(46) { ["_sku"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "sku-21" } ["_downloadable"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "no" } ["_virtual"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "no" } ["_price"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "20" } ["_visibility"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "visible" } ["_stock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["_stock_status"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "instock" } ["_backorders"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "no"

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I added this <?php $custom = get_post_custom($post_id); var_dump($custom); ?> but the same result - a long list of strings. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Read my updated answer.

Comment: I changed the "name_of_your_custom_field" to an appropriate key but getting 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in' and then it points to line 27 which is 'foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {'

Comment: What did you name the field?

Comment: I tried a couple of different custom fields - "Property Released" & "Gender"

Comment: Then you should try $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['"Property Released" & "Gender"'];

Comment: I'm get the same error message - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\wordpress test site\TEST SITE WOO\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\storefront_child\woocommerce\single-product\tabs\description.php on line 27

Comment: I dont know then... It works for me man. Just try using var_dump($custom_fields); and read through the list it spits out until you find your Custom Field.

Comment: When I do that it shows all of the custom fields. I just don't know why it can't display them [" Property Released"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "No" } [" FPS (video)"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "30" } [" Orientation"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Portrait" } [" Number of People"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } [" Gender"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Male" } [" Ages"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Adult" } [" Aerial"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "no" } [" Video Size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "1080" } ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1425006829:1" } }

Comment: You sould unserialize the data

Comment: Thanks Jesper. Could this be the reason it doesn't display the values? My knowledge of php is very limited so if you are able to suggest any code modifications that would be very helpful. Cheers